# How does distributive law in propositional logic apply to two bracketed terms?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

An example of an expression the question is talking about would be: $$(p ∧ ¬q)∨(¬p∨q)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think $\color{blue}{(¬p∨q)}$ as one term, Apply the right distributive law:$$(\color{red}a\land \color{orange}b)\lor \color{blue}c\equiv(\color{red}a\lor \color{blue}c)\land (\color{orange}b\lor \color{blue}c)$$
We have the following:
\begin{align}
& (\color{red}p ∧ \color{orange}{¬q})∨\color{blue}{(¬p∨q)}\\
\equiv&((\color{red}p∨\color{blue}{(¬p∨q)}) ∧ (\color{orange}{¬q}∨\color{blue}{(¬p∨q)})\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Let P be the statement "He's well-read".
Let Q be the statement "He's a good sportsman".

(p∧¬q)∨(¬p∨q) logically equals to : "He's either well-read and bad sportsman, or he's not well-read and good sportsman". You can simply put it P v Q, where v(or) would be exclusive, which means that both can't be true at the same time (although in real life one can be a good sportsman and be well-read, rarely as it is, but still, for the sake of the arguement we'll take it as true.)
So you can write it as> He's either well-read or a good sportsman.